# jQuery tabs using an ID from URL

Tags: url, jquery-ui-tabs

I wonder, how jQuery UI tabs is working - it is switching the tab depends on the ID (`#123`) from the URL address.

I want to do something similar, but I dont know how its working.

If you dont know what ID I mean, here is an example URL: `http://example.com/my_code.php#tab-3`

And if there is an `div` with an ID attribute: `<div id="tab-3">...</div>` then jQuery UI is switching to that tab.

How can I do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On initialization, the jQuery UI tabs widget uses [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to obtain the fragment part of the page's URL, then iterates over the tabs and activates the one that matches the fragment.

The relevant part of the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js) (lines 159 to 166 in the current trunk) is:

```
if (location.hash) {
        this.anchors.each(function(i, a) {
                if (a.hash == location.hash) {
                        o.selected = i;
                        return false; // break
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: There is also a function related to this beggining in function `_tabify` on line 89.

Comment: @Cyclone, glad you found it :) But may I ask, why not use jQuery UI's tab widget instead of rolling your own from scratch? Is that for an educational purpose?

Comment: Could you tell me, how to rewrite this so I can use this in simple jQuery script? Well, I dont want to load such a big library which jQuery UI is, I have written my own jQuery "tabs" with 20 lines~. The second argument I dont want to use it is just that I dont like its design, because I want it to be as simple as possible - here is an image with my tabs design: `http://i.imgur.com/7ksSh.png`. I dont really know how to reach such simple design in jQuery UI tabs, I know I can customize my design with custom colors or patterns only... please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Cyclone, well, I cannot do that without seeing these 20~ lines. Can you update your question with that code?

Comment: Well, nevermind, you gave me an idea to look at jQuery UI - so I've downloaded it, and atm. I've made a pretty nice and simple design within 5 minutes or less, and I dont have problems with tabs interactions anymore `:p`. Thanks!